# Change password auth0 user from react app

Tags: reactjs, auth0, change-password

Are there anyway to change password of auth0 user from react app integrated with it (instead of the form from auth0 domain)? I suppose there is an API which receives email and password parameters and updates it in auth0 side.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where the user authenticates from a certain extent. If they are authenticating from a social connection they will need to reset their password from the initial provider (Google, facebook, etc). However if it's a user name and password then it can be done on the Auth0 side of things. This is covered in the documentation below along with workflow.

https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/password-change

<sub>(Affiliation: I'm Community Lead at Auth0.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for explain, so it means there is no way to achieve the change password on the integrated side (as my case is the react app using auth0 for authentication0?

Comment: "You can only change passwords for users signing in using database connections. Users signing in using social or enterprise connections need to reset their passwords with the appropriate system." - https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/password-change

Comment: Yes, what I mean is the database connection password, but can I change it in the client app (as my react app) instead of from the form of auth0 domain?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the URL provided by the API for this action.

Comment: Hi @Merci Dieu, Did you mean the url to auth0 domain for set new password? Which API return this URL. I only figure out a API which send an email to user with the link to reset password

Comment: If it is your own authentication system (auth0 ), you must provide a URL for this, but if it is via social networks (Google, LinkedIn, Facebook, ...), the user will have to reset his  password on the platform concerned.